# Invalid declaration of or reference error in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

Hello I am new to FORTRAN programming and now going through INTEGERS.

I have the following code Snippet

```
 CHARACTER*14   METFIL

 +                 / 'WKPLT.MET'  /
  CHARACTER*127  IBC
  CHARACTER*2    ICOD(6)
  INTEGER  *2    JIS (6)
 +                 / Z2533, Z2524, Z256B, Z4538, Z332B, Z3F5E  /
```

When I am compiling using g77 I am getting the error  "Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `z2533' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]"  . Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Could give both referenced pieces of code?

Comment: I have added some extra code for better understanding

Comment: Where has `z2533` been seen previously? Is it a constant or a variable?

Comment: For pity's sake if you're learning Fortran, learn good modern Fortran.  VladimirF will be along soon to criticise your use of the non-standard `*n` approach to declaring the size/kind of variables, the `+` signs smack of fixed-form source, `g77` should have been retired about 15 years ago, there are much better free alternatives, I could go on and probably will ....

Comment: Unless you have a *very* specific reason to learn fortran 77 (which is what you're doing now), you *must* switch to modern fortran.

Comment: @Ross Except that isn't F77...

Comment: As that isn't standard Fortran, are you attempting, as @AlexanderVogt's question prompts also, to use a BOZ literal but in a way that another compiler accepted?

Comment: Here is a great Fortran 90 resource http://www.uv.es/dogarcar/man/IntrFortran90.pdf

Comment: according to gnu fortran docs the hex literals should be quoted.  `z'2533'`  Who knows what convention some other compiler might want.  Its not really a bad question by the way, someone might well encounter this in old code and need to fix it.   If you are just "learning stuff" you can skip that part.

Comment: Just checking, both gfortran and ifort accept those literals with or without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I tried to compile your code using g77 . I changed the following

```
  INTEGER  *2    JIS (6)
 +                 / Z'2533', Z'2524', Z'256B', Z'4538', Z'332B', Z'3F5E'  /
```

This was as per agentp's comment above . Hope this helps